# Running threads in order so that they don't conflict

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So, general set up is I have a ListView that gets different values depending on the tab, using fragments.

If I move through the tabs slowely, it works great.  But if I quickly flip through the tabs, they "conflict".  (Items from one tab will appear on the second).

So, my solution was to make Threads that have the runnable parts, then have a queue and add to the queue, then run them off the queue.  I didn't think this would work when I did it, and it didn't.

So, the general code looks like such:

```
final Thread clearThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        MyFragment.adapter.clear();

    }
});
this.threadQueue.add(clearThread);
if (tab == MenuActivity.TITLES.indexOf("My"))
{
    // My Puzzles
    final Activity a = this;
    final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            MyFragment.getUserPuzzles(a);
        }
    });
    this.threadQueue.add(myThread);
}
else if (tab == MenuActivity.TITLES.indexOf("Top"))
{
    // Top Puzzles
    final Activity a = this;
    final Thread topThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            MyFragment.getTopPuzzles(a);
        }
    });
    this.threadQueue.add(topThread);
}
//.... More adding the Thread Queue.

while (this.threadQueue.size() != 0)
{
    final Thread temp = this.threadQueue.poll();
    this.runOnUiThread(temp);
}
```

This is in my FragmentActivity class, where as the methods, adapters, etc. are all in the fragment class (MyFrag).

So, the general question becomes, how can I alter the ListView in a way that it won't conflict with other values being populated while it's being populated.  **Some of the threads do get values online, so depending on the connection, they can be fast or slow**, but it loads so that it adds while it loads.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sync threads you lock the object, and when two threads must always sync with each other it should probably be just one thread. Why not use separate ListView for each tab.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me.  Care to expand it a bit more?  Maybe show some pseudo code?  He has one `ListView` but multiple threads are modifying it in the background it sounds like.

Comment: Yes, sounds like you say. Perhaps he could redesign it to have one ListView per tab with an async task for loading items.

Comment: Gray sort of explained my problem with your solution.  I did however do something very similar to what you said. Gave each tab its own adapter (Or something similar, I don't really know what I did lol, but it works).  I'll mark you as correct as the above didn't help too much.

Answer (score 3):

Put a "current request id" incrementing field in. When you spawn the thread set the request id in the thread. When the thread completes check the field and only update the view if it matches.

i.e.

```
AtomicInteger currentId = new AtomicInteger(0);

new Processor(currentId.incrementAndGet()).start();
```

In the processor

```
if (currentId.get() == ourId) {
   // only here do stuff
}
```

For total safety you could use a synchronized block rather than an AtomicInteger, you probably don't need that in this case but that version would look like:

```
int currentId = 0;
Object lock = new Object();

synchronized(lock) {
    new Processor(++currentId).start();  // Must add then use, not use then add!
}
```

In the processor

```
synchronized(lock) {
    if (currentId == ourId) {
       // only here do stuff
    }
}
```